# jquery animating affecting posistion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a little animation that increases the size of my thumbnail on hover which works but affects the position of the rest of the images.

the problem is when you hover over a img the other img's move down, and right to accommodate for the space taken by the animation. I want the other images not to move as the one is animating.

$num and the for loop is pulling images from a MySQL table, ignore

```
<html>
<?php
for($i; $i < $num; $i++){
echo "<img class='img' id='img" . $i . "' />";
}
?>

<script>
$('.img').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).animate({
                width: "+=14",
                height: "+=14",
                left: "-7",
                bottom: "-7"
            });
        }, function(){
            $(this).animate({
                width: "-=14",
                height: "-=14",
                left: "0",
                bottom: "0"
            });
        }
    );
</script>
<css>
.img{
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpaceDog's answer works quite well if you have at least enough padding to account for adjusting the padding, but in cases where there's no padding this solution might work better:

```
$(function( ){
    $(window).ready(function( ){
        $('.img').each(function( ){
            $(this).css({'top': $(this).offset( ).top, 'left': $(this).offset( ).left});
        });
        $('.img').css({'position': 'absolute', 'z-index': 1});
    });

    $('.img').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).css('z-index', 10);
            $(this).animate({
                width: "+=14",
                height: "+=14",
                left: "-=7",
                top: "+=7"
            });
        }, function(){
            $(this).css('z-index', 1);
            $(this).animate({
                width: "-=14",
                height: "-=14",
                left: "+=7",
                top: "-=7"
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brianpoole/gc872/)

Basically, it loops through each image and sets its top and left position based on its own position, then sets the image's position to absolute so that it won't interfere with any of the elements around it.  So, it takes statically positioned images and makes them absolute without affecting where they're at. Then it animates the images almost exactly how you had originally intended.

Again, SpaceDog's answer works if you're working with enough padding.

Comment: You would have got the +1 just for the kitten pic. :) And that's a neat trick to fix the absolute position of the pictures based on where they're drawn -- however it changes the behavior of the page if you resize the window because they're now in absolute positions. Just a minor note. I noticed he had enough padding and just took the easy option -- thanks for providing a more useful generic answer.

Comment: Haha, I'm glad you liked the kittens and the trick!  The truth is, I hadn't even thought about animating the padding.  Your solution was definitely short and sweet.  More importantly, it got the job done!  I hadn't considered the window resizing, so that's a good point.  Here's a solution I came up with where it takes that into account: http://jsfiddle.net/brianpoole/gc872/4/.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to do what (I think) you want by adjusting the padding in the animation rather than the left/bottom position, like this:

```
$('.img').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).animate({
                width: "+=14",
                height: "+=14",
                padding: "-=7"
            });
        }, function(){
            $(this).animate({
                width: "-=14",
                height: "-=14",
                padding: "+=7"
            });
        }
    );
```

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/h7r9M/).